# Как закинуть аргументы в переменную или лучше в "application.properties" запуская свой архив: java -jar project-1.0.0.jar C:/Document/MyMedia?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Необходимо передать аргумент с запуском jar файла (java -jar project-1.0.0.jar C:/Document/MyMedia) в переменную для хранения пути, куда будут сохраняться файлы. Надо чтобы эта переменная попала в  `application.properties` или присвоилась переменой `uploadPath` в `MyController` с аннотацией `@Value`. У меня есть решение, но считаю оно неправильное. Мой код:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyController.uploadPath=args[0];
        //Это конечно "костыль" и топорное решение, но только так придумал
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MyController {

     @Value("${upload.path}")
    String uploadPath;

 // public static String uploadPath;
     // Это костыль
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить переменную в application.properties и читаешь в не jar

```
java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=optional:file:./myconfig.properties
```

Есть другие варианты в документации:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config